# Prevent Dojo DropdownMenu from closing

Tags: javascript, dojo

I use a Dojo Enhanced Grid to display various data. With a DropDownMenu I give the user the ability to show additional colums.
But this is a little bit uncomfortable. Because the user has to click for every new colum onto the menu.
Is there a possibility to prevent the DropDownMenu from closing? Or should I use another widget for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look into Dojo [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/), and the ColumnHider [extension](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Extensions). It effectively recreates what you're doing, and is available out-of-the-box, including the feature you're after.

An alternate solution is to use a [dijit/TooltipDialog](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/TooltipDialog.html), whose default behavior is to stay open when one of its contents is clicked.

Comment: Actually this isn't an option... . I have to use the Enhanced Grid, because my boss won't allow me to change the grid right now... .  
And the only thing that isn't working the way I want to, is that the DropDown Menu disappiers after the first click.

Comment: I've spent a good amount of time trying to achieve what you're after, and it seems that the best option is to use a dijit/TooltipDialog. I prefer the DropDownMenu, but there isn't a clearly documented way to prevent it from closing when an item is clicked; this "stay open" behavior is the default for a dijit/TooltipDialog.

Answer (score 0):

yourGrid.openDropDown(); will open the menu back again, and you would not really notice that it was displayed back again after a close.